# proper tube size for bicycle tire

Tags: tire, innertube

My bicycle tire specification is 40-622 (700x38C-28x1 5/8 x 1 1/2), would you please tell me the right size of the proper inner tube?

Comment: To summarise the answers to the questions which this duplicates: tubes have a range. Get a tube with the right wheel diameter (700c in your case) and a tyre wish range that includes the width of your tyre. You might be able to get a 700c x 32-38 or 700c x 35-42 for example, depending on the make.

Comment: If  I couldn't  find a wide 700c I would use the narrowest 29er tube available. Most likely a 29x1.75( approx. 44mm).